# My Genymotion emulators don't see the host file

Tags: android, android-studio, genymotion

I'm using `Genymotion` in testing my `Android` apps and it was working fine , my company changed their URLs to new ones and asked from us to add these new URLs in the host file , we did that but when I try to test my `Android` app on the `Genymotion` I get

`Webpage not available the webpage at "company url" could not loaded because net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

And when I try it on the real device I get `this site can't be reached` .

When I make a ping on these URLs I get a result but I don't know why the `Genymotion` don't see the host file

I'm in this problem for 3 days I need a solution .

Comment: Is it HTTPS URL?